# Typed yield expression in MobX-State-Tree flow

Tags: typescript, mobx, mobx-state-tree

The recommended way to do asynchronous actions in MobX-state-tree (MST) is to use [`flow`](https://mobx-state-tree.js.org/concepts/async-actions), which takes a generator function as first argument in which every promise should be yielded.

[`yield` expressions are of type `any` in TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2983#issuecomment-230414026), but is there any way to automatically type a yield expression in MST?

**Example**

```js
import { flow, types } from "mobx-state-tree";

type Stuff = { id: string; name: string };

function fetchStuff(): Promise<Stuff[]> {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve([
      { id: "1", name: "foo" },
      { id: "2", name: "bar" }
    ]);
  });
}

const Thing = types.model({
  id: types.identifier,
  name: types.string
});

const ThingStore = types
  .model({
    things: types.array(Thing)
  })
  .actions((self) => ({
    fetchThings: flow(function* () {
      // "stuff" is of type "any"!
      const stuff = yield fetchStuff();
      self.things.replace(stuff);
    })
  }));
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[toGenerator](https://mobx-state-tree.js.org/API/#togenerator) can be used to convert a promise to a generator yielding that promise. This together with `yield*` instead of `yield` (which is made available by setting [`downlevelIteration` to `true` in the TypeScript compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html#compiler-options)) makes it so the promise return type is retained.

```js
import { flow, types, toGenerator } from "mobx-state-tree";

type Stuff = { id: string; name: string };

function fetchStuff(): Promise<Stuff[]> {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve([
      { id: "1", name: "foo" },
      { id: "2", name: "bar" }
    ]);
  });
}

const Thing = types.model({
  id: types.identifier,
  name: types.string
});

const ThingStore = types
  .model({
    things: types.array(Thing)
  })
  .actions((self) => ({
    fetchThings: flow(function* () {
      // "stuff" is now of type "Stuff[]"!
      const stuff = yield* toGenerator(fetchStuff());
      self.things.replace(stuff);
    })
  }));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to use typescript or babel transform plugins to do that translation only later:

- https://github.com/aurornz/ts-transform-async-to-mobx-flow
- https://github.com/Strate/babel-plugin-mobx-async-action

In native Typescript, it's sadly not possible (yet) to describe the return type of `yield` - see [details in this issue](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/2091)