# Typescript does not infer promise type when using yield in a generator function

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios, generator, mobx-state-tree

I'm using Axios to handle some API fetching, and I'm executing that call within a generator; `async/await` is not an option for this particular project.  For some reason, even though `axios` is getting my types right, typescript is inferring an `any` type when I use the `yield` keyword.

```
function* foo() {
  // axios.get is returning Promise<AxiosResponse<T>>
  // but data is being inferred as "any"
  const { data } = yield axios.get<T>(url); 
  
  // do some stuff with data
}
```

If I specfically type the axios response, it works fine, but I feel like I'm missing something, since TS isn't getting the type automatically

```
function* foo() {
  const { data }: AxiosResponse<T> = yield axios.get<T>(url); 
  
  // do some stuff with data
}
```

Is there some other step or config I'm missing?

Here's my tsconfig

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "jsx": "react",
    "removeComments": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "rootDirs": ["src", "src/stories"],
    "paths": {
      "*": ["./src/custom-types/*"]
    },
    "types": ["@emotion/core", "jest"]
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*"]
}
```

Comment: @ikhvjs - *"`async/await` is not an option for this particular project."*

Comment: Can you show us the call to this function?

Comment: How is `async`/`await` not an option? Especially since you are using the typescript compiler, and are fine with generator functions?

Comment: @Bergi the library I'm using (mobx-state-tree) has a preferred method for handling async actions, and recommends against async/await.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65374058/3617886) might give some inspiration as well.

Comment: @KevinWhitaker - FWIW, see this article: https://coolsoftware.dev/blog/write-async-await-with-mobx-state-tree/ by one of the `mobx-state-tree` contributors about using `async`/`await` with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Preface:** You've said you can't use `async`/`await` because you're using `mobx-state-tree`, which says [you can't use it](https://mobx-state-tree.js.org/concepts/async-actions#what-about-async--await) on protected trees. But see [this article](https://coolsoftware.dev/blog/write-async-await-with-mobx-state-tree/) on how to use `async`/`await` successfully with it. (Basically, instead of directly updating things in your `async` function, you call an action to do it.) It's on the blog of Tyler Williams, one of the contributors to `mobx-state-tree`. I found it in March 2024; no idea when it was written, it's undated ☹️ and not in archive.org.  He says they're working on updating the `mobx-state-tree` documentation.*

Answering the generator question:

TypeScript can't infer the type of the `yield` operation, because that's controlled by the calling code. In your case, it sounds like this generator is being used by code that handles the promise from axios and responds by providing the axios result in the call to `g.next`. That makes sense if you're in an environment where you can't use `async`/`await`; generators can be used to allow async logic to flow more clearly, where the generator is driven by a helper that gets the promise from the generator, waits for it to settle, then passes the fulfillment value back to the generator via `next` — `yield` largely takes the role of `await` when doing that. ([`co`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/co) is one example of a library that enables using generators this way.) So the code *using* the generator expects the generator to yield a `Promise` and it gives back the promise's fulfillment value. In this case, that would be yielding a `Promise<AxiosResponse<T>>` and getting back an `AxiosResponse<T>`.

To handle that, you need to annotate the function using the `Generator` type, which accepts three type parameters:

- `T` - the type of what the generator *produces* via `yield`.
- `TReturn` - the type of what the generator *returns* when done.
- `TNext` - the type of what the generator *consumes* (receives from `yield`).

So applying that to your example, we'd add a generic type parameter to `foo` and annotate it with `Generator`:

```typescript
function* foo<T>(): Generator<Promise<AxiosResponse<T>>, ReturnType, AxiosResponse<T>> {
    const { data } = yield axios.get<T>(url); 
    
    // ...do some stuff with data...

    return /*...something of `ReturnType` (or use `void` as the type argument above)... */;
}
```

---

Just for anyone who isn't as familiar with `yield` and generators as they might like, here's an example where the generator produces strings, returns a boolean, and consumes numbers ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mAVAAgKYA8CGBbADgG1QAoBKALmQHFUxUAnTKOOgHgGco6YwBzAGmQAjOHEKYwAsCGyD6APmQBvAFDI1yCAg7JMyALzIAnjFT4AJsgBEmSwG5V6zWDajUAOnxweRAAYAlVAhUGAA3VAsAEkVMAF9kYGYdHxJ7dQ0tKCF9IxNzK0E7BzUnF0IPL18AoNDw5CjBOIS6IWTUxwyNbONTC0sIQrSS13Lvf0DgsMjFCEbEiFai9OdM4HxMHmyiXQBqIRJkBQg2tTpUKBA6MHi1nnsY5WUSzI2DDBwCYhTlQkzTthB8JkDDw3LR0FBSPYhmVPN4-gCoG4Qph8CBUCk1AB6TFWGzKeGA7IgsEQgCMGLSaWxyAACpg2GxUGxkKTkEw2QALVDIHg0eiMZiPLTDWFEAmI5Go9G2LE4ywFfFMhFE0EYCEAJgplNltPpjOZ6rZcE53N5tAYTDoQucIoq4qRKLRFOpfUsiv%20hOBqvBRAAzFrtdS6QymchfUaTTy%20RbBdD3KL7ZKnTLkNTgCjGQJWbtDQpwzBmen8IygA)):

```typescript
function* example(): Generator<string, boolean, number> {
    const a = yield "a";
    console.log(`Received ${a} for a`);
    const b = yield "b";
    console.log(`Received ${b} for b`);
    const c = yield "c";
    console.log(`Received ${c} for c`);
    const flag = (a + b) > c;
    return flag;
}

const g = example();
let result = g.next();
console.log(result.value);  // "a"
result = g.next(1);         // Passes 1 to the generator
// (Generator logs "Received 1 for a")
console.log(result.value);  // "b"
result = g.next(2);         // Passes 2 to the generator
// (Generator logs "Received 2 for b")
console.log(result.value);  // "c"
result = g.next(3);         // Passes 3 to the generator
// (Generator logs "Received 3 for c")
console.log(result.value);  // false (1 + 2 > 3 is false)
```